# PG::Error: ERROR: relation "mailboxer_notifications" does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailboxer, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I just updated to rails 4.1 and mailboxer doesn't seem happy for the change. Below is what happens when I try to get inbox from my console.

```
 [18] snifme »  Master.last.mailbox.inbox
  Master Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "masters".* FROM "masters"   ORDER BY "masters"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "mailboxer_notifications" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"mailboxer_notifications"...
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"mailboxer_notifications"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum

(pry) output error: #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  relation "mailboxer_notifications" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"mailboxer_notifications"...
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"mailboxer_notifications"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
```

Does anything stand out as fixable? I'm in development environment. thanks

Comment: why the downvote on this one? this is a gem issue, not an obvious postgresql trivial issue he/she missed

Answer (score 4):

I found that I needed to run `$ rails generate mailboxer:namespacing_compatibility`for rails 4.1 upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same issue and above command will not working for me.

You need to mention the 'mailboxer' gem version to '0.11.0' in Gemfile.
If you do not mention any version it could use higher version (currently '0.12.0' is higher) and your page can break.

It happens on production environment (heroku etc) mostly.

> gem 'mailboxer', '0.11.0'

Thanks.

Comment: README mentions to run the command from the other answer when upgrading to 0.12.0. More details here: https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer#upgrading